# Reject second attempt login in spring security

Tags: spring-security, login-control

in my project, the user only can login once, and when any user want to login with the same userid, the attempt to login will be rejected. and the user that login first will give a notice that any attempt to login with their user id.

how to configure spring security to apply this behavior? is there any build in configuration in spring security context can handle this behavior?

thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a build in Feature from Spring Security Called the [ConcurrentSessionFilter or Controller](http://www.chibi.ubc.ca/maven2/jars.to.deploy/spring-security-2.0.5/docs/apidocs/org/springframework/security/concurrent/ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl.html). Have a look at that.

Once configured it should provide you the functionality you're looking for

UPDATE:
[Configuration](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Concurrent+Sessions+%28Preventing+Users+from+Logging+in+More+Than+Once%29)

Comment: hi hons, thanks for your answer. what filter you think that appropriate with my case? for both of the case.

Comment: Actually I've never used it myself, I've just seen it in action. If you follow the link in the above post you'll see the javadoc of the filter. Actually the configuration seems to be quite easy and probably you just need to add it to your application context, which is the link I've added above